# Pipes & exec & C

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe, exec

Hi i have the following problem , I have to create a program that performs these Linux commands  `ls –la | sort | wc –l` but in my code i just can read two of this command , can sameone help me with this??

```
int main(){
  pid_t pids[3];
   int dados[2],dados2[2],i;

    if(pipe(dados) == -1 && pipe(dados2) == -1){
       perror("pipe failed");
       exit(1);
     }

  for(i=0;i<3;i++){
      pids[i] = fork();
      if(pids[i] == 0){ 
          if(i==0){
            close(dados[0]);
            dup2(dados[1],1);
            close(dados[1]);

            execlp("ls","ls","-la",NULL);
            perror("exec failed");
            exit(-1);
        }
        if(i==1){
            close(dados[1]);
            dup2(dados[0],0);
            close(dados[0]);


            close(dados2[0]);
            dup2(dados2[1],1);
            close(dados2[1]);

            execlp("sort","sort",NULL);
            perror("exec failed");
            exit(-1);
         }else{
            close(dados2[1]);
            dup2(dados2[0],0);
            close(dados2[0]);
            printf("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            execlp("wc","wc","-l",NULL);
            perror("exec failed");
            exit(-1);
         }
     }
 }

 /* Pai tem de fechar a sua copia da extremidade de escrita 
  para a leitura do sort desbloquear */
 close(dados[1]);
 close(dados2[0]);
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
     wait(NULL);
 }

return 0;
```

}

i dont understand what miss in this

Answer (score 0):

What catches my eye immediatly is

```
-if(pipe(dados) == -1 && pipe(dados2) == -1){
+if(pipe(dados) == -1 || pipe(dados2) == -1){

   perror("pipe failed");
   exit(1);
}
```

The parent pid just needs to read the output of the last command, so the parent neeeds to close all other pipe ends. The child processes needs to close stdin/stdout and dup2() the pipe descriptors to bind them to stdin/stdout and then exec(). With pipes it is really important that you close the not needed pipe end in your process. See http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe

Currently i dont have an linux box beneith me, so i cant write and test linux code.

My summary for you is:
- parent reads from the last pipe (stdout of the last process in the chain)
- all other childs need to close() their stdin/stdout, dup2() the right pipeend, close all unneeded pipes (remember to close the dup2() source too, because it is a fd) and then exec.

Here is an example how i did create a pipe and rebind the fds.

```
// unset FD_CLOEXEC
set_close_on_exec(to_child,false);
set_close_on_exec(from_child, false);

// close and rebind the stdin/stdout/stderr
// dup the fd and recreate stdin/stdout with fd as the target
if (dup2(to_child, STDIN_FILENO) != 0 || dup2(from_child, STDOUT_FILENO) != 1) {
    shared::perror("error duplicating socket for stdin/stdout");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// close these FDs
close(to_child);
close(from_child);

// now we can exec the new sub process and talk to it through
// stdin/stdout/stderr
execlp(exe.c_str(), exe.c_str(), argv.c_str(), (char*)0);

// this should never be reached
shared::perror("error: executing the binary: " + exe);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Remember that at pipe(int fds[2]) the index 1 is the write end of the pipe and index 0 is the read end of the pipe. So you need

Regards
Georg

Edit: I recommend you the book "The Linux Programming Interface: A Linux and UNIX System Programming Handbook" ISBN-13: 978-1593272203